# discord.js adding numbers with a command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a discord bot that add/removes a number every time a Admin runs a command, Here's an example of what I'm trying to say. !addstrike then make the bot respond 2/3 strikes. I'm new at coding around js so sorry if this is confusing, I'm trying to learn...

Thanks you.

Comment: Maybe you can first try out some tutorials? https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/9eb5sv/learn_to_make_a_discord_bot_with_javascript/

Comment: Thank you, i'll read it.

Comment: This question is hard to answer. Can you please specify at what part you problem lies? Also, your current progress would be quite helpfull.